# What is "ну ты ваще!"?

Tags: перевод, одним-словом

I've seen once

> ну ты ваще!

somewhere. Is it related to "вообще" as the redirection to that word in Wiktionary suggests?

In that case, what is the whole thing? Since I feel like it's missing an adjective, does it mean something by itself? I'd expected "ну ты ваще дурак/умный!"

Comment: "Is it related to "вообще" as the redirection to that word in Wiktionary suggests?" - Yes, it is intentional mispronouncing and misspelling of `вообще`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This phrase is an emotional exclamation. You are right, it's related to `вообще` and it skips the main word. This missing word is usually known from a context and an intonation. It can has either positive or negative meaning.

Examples:

- `Ну ты ваще дебил!` negative exclamation, noun is used.
- `Ну ты ваще молодец!` positive exclamation, noun is used.
- `Ну ты ваще красивый!` positive (humorous?) exclamation, adjective is used.
- `Ну ты ваще герой!` positive (humorous?) exclamation, noun is used.

So my answer is: this phrase has no self-explanatory meaning without a context.

Answer (score 1):

Actually this is a synonym for "Ну ты даешь!", wiktionary defines it as an exclamation when someone does [something unexpected](https://ru.wiktionary.org/wiki/%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C):

> неперех., разг. делать что-то неожиданное ◆ Ну ты даёшь!

For instance, when a man in a typical businessman outfit suddenly makes a somersault a natural reaction would be "Ну ты даешь!".